# A printer's SNMP community name is the default "public", will changing it affect it's use?

Tags: printer, string, snmp

I'd like to change it from the default "public" as a part of removing vulnerabilities in the workplace.

Also, can the "read only", "read/write", and "trap" community names use the same strings?

Comment: So all three community names can use the same string assuming it meets the required characters?

Answer (score 3):

Changing the community string should not affect the core functions of a printer (-> printing). Only software using SNMP will be affected, things like network inventory or management software. You may have software using SNMP without you ever configuring it, a lot of software will try to use "public" by default.

Whether you can use the same community string for "read", "read/write" and "traps" depends on the firmware. There is nothing in the SNMP protocol preventing it.

If you are concerned about security you should realise that SNMP v1 and v2.c are not secure. The community string is not a password and should not be confused with one. It is transmitted over the network in cleartext, intercepting it with a packet sniffer is childs play. For this reason do not ever use a community string that is also a password for something else.

SNMP v3 does offer security (if configured correctly) but not all devices support it.